# Is there a pythonic way for loop and use previous item

Tags: python

For example, I have a array X [1, 3, 2, 5, 1, 3], I need a new array like a moving window, find the smallest in every 3 items ==> [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1]

I know I can loop from array len() and use list slip, but Is there a pythonic way for this problem?

I tried X[1] and found type(X[1]) is a int and cannot trace back the the array X.

Thank you for your help.

edited: sorry for the inconvenient. i made a mistake above.
for window 1, only the first element 1, so output 1
    window 2: [1,3] -> 1
    window 3: [1, 3, 2] -> 1
    window 4: [3, 2, 5] -> 2

btw the anwsers is very helpful. thank you.

Comment: Your expected output doesn't even make sense.

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail how you get your expected output? It seems to me that there should only be _one_ leading `1`.

Comment: If I have understood your question, the expected output should be `[1, 2, 1, 1]`, not `[1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1]`...

Comment: @sshashank124 you can write a program that will produce any given output. The OP was not clear in specifying what he/she meant, but certainly you cannot say it does not make sense now.

Comment: You really need to explain how you came to this output.

Comment: Thank you so much, I made a mistake in OP. and the answer for rolling window is very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [33]: X = [1, 3, 2, 5, 1, 3]

In [34]: list(map(min, (X[i:i+3] for i in range(len(X)-2))))
Out[34]: [1, 2, 1, 1]
```

Comment: This does not yield the expected output in the question. Maybe the OP wanted something different, you should wait untile he/she clarifies.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo: I already commented, asking for clarification from OP. Since OP seems unresponsive to comments on the question itself, I figured I'd give it a shot, hoping to hit something close to what OP is looking for

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Thanks a lot, that's what I need. and I hope the window rolls from the first and single element, I'll solve this.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo Thank you, I made a mistake in OP. the third number should be 1. I've updated it.

Answer (score 1):

```
map(min, zip(a[1:]+[max(a)], [max(a)]+a, a+[max(a)]))
```

I don't know if it is a pythonic way. It's just a tricky one-liner and is not preferable to ordinary loop.

Comment: +1 coz it gives desired output

Comment: -1 coz it's ugly and inefficient

Answer (score 0):

```
def pairwise( iterable, n=2 ):
    from itertools import tee, izip, islice
    return izip(*(islice(it,pos,None) for pos,it in enumerate(tee(iterable, n))))

 x = [1, 3, 2, 5, 1, 3]


list(pairwise(x,3))
#[(1, 3, 2), (3, 2, 5), (2, 5, 1), (5, 1, 3)]
map(min, pairwise(x,3))
#[1, 2, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks, itertools is very helpful. learning.

Answer (score 0):

```
history = collections.deque((None, None), 2)  # sentinel
for x in your_input:
    result = min(x, min(history))
    history.append(x)
```

Choice of sentinel depends on how you want to treat start of input.

Or if this is clearer

```
window = collections.deque((), 3)
for x in your_input:
    window.append(x)
    result = min(window)
```

First uses explicit history as OP subject, last explicit window.

`deque` with size argument automatically drops off elements from the other end on append when size is exceeded.